# Shorten with match

Tags: scheme, racket

how can I replace the if statements with match that the code is easier to read and understand?

```
(: f (t1 -> integer))
(define f
(lambda (x)
   (if (natural? (t1-b x))
       (+ (t1-a x)
          (t1-b x)
          (t1-c x))
       (if (and (= (t2-e (t1-b x)) 1)
                (= (t2-d (t1-b x)) 1))
           10
           (- (+ (t2-d (t1-b x))
                 (t2-e (t1-b x)))
              (t1-a x))))))
```

Comment: Where is the definition of `t1`? It looks like it's some kind of struct, so can you show the struct definition?

Comment: How you might use `match` will depend on the struct definitions of both `t1` and `t2`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good use case for `match`, the conditions are not a good fit for pattern matching. But we can simplify the nested conditionals using `cond`:

```
(define (f x)
  (cond ((natural? (t1-b x))
         (+ (t1-a x)
            (t1-b x)
            (t1-c x)))
        ((and (= (t2-e (t1-b x)) 1)
              (= (t2-d (t1-b x)) 1))
         10)
        (else
         (- (+ (t2-d (t1-b x))
               (t2-e (t1-b x)))
            (t1-a x)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide the struct definitions for `t1` or `t2`, so I will make a guess.

```
(struct t1 [a b c] #:transparent)
(struct t2 [d e] #:transparent)
```

Assuming those definitions match what you have, I can translate each branch-question and answer.

#### Branch 1, condition using the `?` pattern, naming to eliminate selectors

The first branch condition `(natural? (t1-b x))` can be translated to

```
(t1 _ (? natural?) _)
```

The `?` pattern applies a predicate to the value it's matched against, and only matches when the predicate returns true. To find its documentation, search for `(? expr pat ...)` in the [match documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._match%29%29).

And, since you use the selectors `t1-a`, `t1-b`, and `t1-c` in the branch-answer, you can name them

```
(t1 a (? natural? b) c)
```

So that the whole branch looks like

```
[(t1 a (? natural? b) c)
 (+ a b c)]
```

#### Branch 2, using literal-patterns like `1`

The second branch condition

```
(and (= (t2-e (t1-b x)) 1)
     (= (t2-d (t1-b x)) 1))
```

Can be translated to

```
(t1 _ (t2 1 1) _)
```

And, since you don't use any selectors in the branch-answer, it doesn't help to name the wildcards, and the whole question-answer pair can be translated to

```
[(t1 _ (t2 1 1) _)
 10]
```

#### Branch 3, eliminating nested selectors starting inside-out

For this one, there is no branch-question, but there are selectors used in the body:

```
(- (+ (t2-d (t1-b x))
      (t2-e (t1-b x)))
   (t1-a x))))
```

First eliminate the selectors for `t1` on `x`:

```
[(t1 a b _)
 (- (+ (t2-d b)
       (t2-e b))
    a)]
```

Then eliminate the selectors for `t2` on `b`:

```
[(t1 a (t2 d e) _)
 (- (+ d e)
    a)]
```

#### Putting it together

Put the three branches together in `(match x branch1 branch2 ...)` in the body

```
; assuming these struct definitions
(struct t1 [a b c] #:transparent)
(struct t2 [d e] #:transparent)

(: f (t1 -> integer))
(define f
  (lambda (x)
    (match x
      [(t1 a (? natural? b) c)
       (+ a b c)]
      [(t1 _ (t2 1 1) _)
       10]
      [(t1 a (t2 d e) _)
       (- (+ d e)
          a)])))
```